# Does Rust have hooks for early return on errors?

Tags: error-handling, rust, hook

`panic!` [allows the setting of a custom (albeit global) hook](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html). Is there anything comparable for early returns with the `?` operator? I have a function that needs to close some resources in a special way before exiting. I could write a function `ok_or_close()` that closes the resources before returning the error:

```
fn opens_resources() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    //Opens some stuff.

    //Now a bunch of functions that might raise errors.
    ok_or_close(foo(), local variables)?;
    ok_or_close(bar(), local variables)?;
    ok_or_close(baz(), local variables)?;

    ok_or_close(Ok(()), local variables)
}
```

But that seems verbose. What I'd really like to do is this:

```
fn opens_resources() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    //Opens some stuff.

    //Now a bunch of functions that might raise errors.
    foo()?;
    bar()?;
    baz()?;

on_err:
    //Closes some stuff. Would prefer not to make
    //  this a function, uses many local variables.
    Ok(())
}
```

Is there a way to do this or a pattern of programming that gets around this?

Comment: The normal approach would be the "Open some stuff" creating an RAII wrapper. Maybe it would help if you elaborated more on what issues you have with that approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to this would be the `Try` trait which allows you to implement how ? affect a specific type, but sadly it is still a nightly experiment as stated [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html)

If you're interested in this features I'd recommend you give a +1 at this [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42327)